# How to make "my posts" page

Tags: posts

1. How to make a section, or better is something like a shortcode, to
   filter only posts added by me (or other user, depends on who is
   logged in)?
2. And how to hide this page (section) if is nobody logged in?

Comment: Please explain your problem better, and post the code you are working with. As is, it looks like you have two questions: 1) How can you retrieve posts via a shortcode? and 2) how can you hide shortcode content from people who are not logged in? I am pretty sure both have already been asked and answered here.

Comment: Really thanks for answers, code is a wordpress functions php file or i misunderstood what you need, and yes it is two questions but i think its part of one code of some button. to be honest i am looking for real answer for days and nothing what i need, but my problem is for my opinion easy to understand, i just maybe cant ask correctly because i am not fluent in english... now i am trying to use that code what you gave me, how to use that code? when I copy it to function file, what next? it add some new shortcode?

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: I think the thing is more more simple, but i cant find how to correct edit shortcode: [display-posts author="bill"] no "bill" but 'current_user', if you know what i mean...

Comment: Please add comments about my answer to my answer and not to the question. you didn't ask for a shortcode where you could identify a user. You asked for one that shows posts for the ___current___ user.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
function my_posts_shortcode_wpse_135655() {
  if (!is_user_logged_in()) return;
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  if (!empty($current_user->ID)) {
    $userp = new WP_Query(
      array(
        'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
      )
    );
    $content = '';
    if ($userp->have_posts()) {
      while ($userp->have_posts()) {
        $userp->the_post();
        $content .= get_the_title();
      }
    } else {
      $content .= "You don't have any posts.";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $content;
  }
}
add_shortcode('my_posts','my_posts_shortcode_wpse_135655');
```

Stepping through it:

1. Do nothing if the user is not logged in
2. Else retrieve the user data for the logged in user
3. If we have user data run query to get the user posts
4. Output the titles of those posts
5. Reset post data

To use this shortcode, just add `[my_posts /]` to any post or page.

Comment: Its not working, it only outputs names of recent posts, no grid or separated values and on different users same result, i will try to use logic of this code... it seems to be right, the think is in wordpress header list i want to have page (menu-list) where will be my post (post added by loged user if not( else as you write in code)) in same format like on default formatted recent post, just with some " only my own-posts"filter

Comment: All I did was echo the title. It is proof of concept code. Whatever other formatting you want is pure PHP, HTML, and CSS, and you didn't ask for that in the question anyway. You need to add that part yourself.

Comment: yes i know... but when i try from different users and permissions it has still same result (admin submitted posts)